# Exporting data of different lengths to a table with headers

Tags: matlab, export

I want to export data from Matlab to a datafile.
I want the exported table to have separate data for each column and headers. My problem is, that I don't know how to get this for different datalengths.

Here is a small example showing, what I want to export:

header1   header2   header3 
 0     2     3 
       2     3 
             3

Comment: Perhaps you can padd your data with `NaN` to get the desired result?
Or make it a string and use empty strings or spaces?

Comment: I ended up using empty strings for the empty cells, which after all in all seems like the best way to do it. Thank you.